# Case insensitive SELECT using "IN"

Tags: mysql, search

Can I make a case insensitive IN operation for select in mysql? for example I have a table named "user" and a field name firstName. I want to find all "John, Stark".

can I write the query as

```
SELECT firstName FROM user WHERE firstName IN ("JOHN", "STARK")
```

Comment: what is the collation of your table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could just do `UPPER(firstName)` if the case of `IN` values doesn't matter.

Comment: the case of IN values does matter. I solved it using php assigning IN values I turned all IN values to uppercase then used UPPER(firstName) :). thank you mate!